# Big O for this code

Tags: java, time-complexity

Below code is from topcoder website. I was trying to figure the time complexity for this code. There is 1 for loop and 1 while loop in the method isRandom and 1 for loop in the method diff. I guess the worst case scenario would be O(n^2). Is that correct?

```
public class CDPlayer { 
private boolean[] used; 

public boolean diff(String str, int from, int to) { 
Arrays.fill(used, false); 
to = Math.min(to, str.length()); 
for (int i = from; i < to; i++) { 
  if (used[str.charAt(i) - 'A']) { 
    return false; 
  } 
  used[str.charAt(i) - 'A'] = true; 
} 
return true; 
} 

public int isRandom(String[] songlist, int n){ 
  String str = ""; 
  for (int i = 0; i < songlist.length; i++) { 
    str += songlist[i]; 
  } 

  used = new boolean[26]; 
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    if (!diff(str, 0, i)) { 
      continue; 
    } 

    int j = i; 
    boolean bad = false; 
    while (j < str.length()) { 
      if (!diff(str, j, j + n)) { 
        bad = true; 
        break; 
      } 
      j += n; 
    } 
    if (bad) { 
      continue; 
    } 
    return i; 
  } 

  return -1; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out something like this `O(S) + O(n^2) + O(SS)*O(n^2)`, where

S = songlist.length, SS = sum of all song lengths. So your complexity depends on various inputs and it can't be represented by simple value.

P.S. Note that String is immutable object, so better use StringBuilder.

Before:

```
String str = ""; 
  for (int i = 0; i < songlist.length; i++) { 
    str += songlist[i]; 
  }
```

After:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < songlist.length; i++) { 
    builder.append(songlist[i]); 
  }
```

In that case you won't create new String object on each iteration

Comment: There's still a worst case for (n,S,SS) that can be expressed as a function of SS, so it *can* be represented by a simple value, even if figuring it out isn't so simple. Also, depending on threading issues, I'd use StringBuilder, not StringBuffer. :)

Answer (score -2):

As "n" is not the size of the input, it can not really be O(n) or O(n^2).
If m is the length of all strings in songlist, then you are jumping over that string in steps of the size n. So the compelxity is related to m not to n. I did not calculate in big O etc. since a few decades ... however I would assume the complexity is O(m).